# padding around certain char

Tags: python, string

I have for example this dict:

```
dict = { "(": " ( ", ")": " ) " ... }
```

and I have string, for example : `"if (x < 0) {"`
and I want it to be `"if ( x < 0 ) {"`

what is the way to do it? (its not important to use the dictionary, the important is to add padding around certain chars)

Comment: What problems did you encounter implementing this?

Comment: the dictionary could be useful. I think you could use some regex in this case.

Comment: For your dictionary above containing the chars, can those chars exist in strings with 1. no padding 2. semi-padding (left or right) or 3. full padding?

Comment: Be careful with naming your dictionary `dict`, it may mess up future type-casting. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid double-spaces in case padding already exists (as in your example), you could use a regular expression instead, using lookaheads and lookbehind to find places where a character that needs padding is preceeded `(?<=...)` or followed by `(?=...)` a non-space character `\S`:

```
>>> padding = "()"
>>> p = r"(?<=\S)(?=[{0}])|(?<=[{0}])(?=\S)".format(padding)
>>> re.findall(p, text)
['', '']
>>> re.sub(p, " ", text)
'if ( x < 0 ) {'
```

Comment: is it possible to do it on non-strings, meaning for str = " string a = "aaa()" " so it wont add padding to things that are inside strings?

Comment: @johnStr That's tricky... it might be easier to just add padding before the `(` if the word before is one of `if`, `for`, `while`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
def pad(s):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        s = s.replace(k, v)
    return s

>>> dictionary = { "(": " ( ", ")": " ) "}
>>> pad("if (x < 0) {")
'if  ( x < 0 )  {'
```